# Automate cross tabulation and significance testing of dataframe?

Tags: r, crosstab, significance

It seems this should be ludicrously easy, but I cannot find it. I have a dataframe with id, sex, ..., age, Q1, ..., Q2, etc.

```
# EXAMPLE CODE
big.data= data.frame(ID= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), sex= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,NA), 
age= c(25,25,35,NA,35,45,45), Q1= c(1,2,NA,2,2,2,2), Q2= c(1,NA,2,2,3,3,3) )
```

I want to select sex ... age as categories and Q1 ... Q2 as variables of interest. I want R to produce CSV tables for each category by variable of interest (four tables in this example) that are similar to this in information (not necessarily format or layout) (with count and percentage of column by response to question):

[image]

This table for Q2 by sex shows result of Chi-squared test for whole table and significance test between all responses to sex for each response to Q2 that are p< 0.05. That is, when 100% of males and 0% of females respond to Q2 with 1, I want to know if this is significant.

**How can this be easily done in R?**

Comment: You might take a look at the `aggregate` function in base R, or the `group_by` and then `summarize` functions in the 'dplyr' package.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/882/